# jQuery How to animate floating spans after remove on of them from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have 4 `<span/>` (or div's, whatever)

[1] [2] [3] [4]

each container has inside an input which causes that it's container is being removed frome the DOM.

If I click at the input in the container [2], it is removed and the container [3] and [4] immideatly moves to the left:

[1] [3] [4]

**I'm wondering how to animate that process - slow it a bit ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would depend on your CSS.

If they are floated to the left, then all you'd have to do is animate the width of #2 to `0` before you remove it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/a6NPP/

```
$(myspan).animate({width:0}, 600, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

This assumes there's no border/padding/margin. If so, you'd need to animate the left/right properties of those as well, or place each one in a container with `overflow:hidden`, and animate the width of that.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/), it has [many effects you can use](http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/).

Comment: Hmm, I checked Your example, but if I remove the 2nd span, why the containers 1,3,4 goes down a bit while the 2nd is animating ?

Comment: @Tony  - Not sure. It doesn't do that for me. Probably a CSS issue in whatever browser you're using. This will be somewhat dependent upon the CSS you're using. This just shows how to animate the width of an element.

Answer (score 1):

Apply some animation on span and remove it in callback function. Something like that:

```
$('span').hide('slow',function(){
    this.remove();
});
```